# Upgrade SharePoint sandbox solution without deactivate-activate feature on each sub site

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can I upgrade SharePoint sandbox solution on multiple sub sites without deactivate-activate feature on each sub site

Current I need to

1. **Deactivate** **feature** from each sub site
2. **Deactivate** **solution** from main site
3. Upload a new **solution** and **activate** it
4. **Activate** **feature** on each sub site.

Answer (score 2):

In such case, you can create a `PowerShell` script. I am not having the exact code, but I used the following logic:

**For First Time**

1. Add the Sandbox Solution using `Add-SPUserSolution`.
2. Install the solution using `Install-SPUserSolution`.
3. Now get solution ID using `Get-SPUserSolution`
4. Next get all the features within solution using `Get-SPFeature`
5. Check if feature is not enabled use `Enable-SPFeature` cmdlet to activate it.

**When Updating**

Simply run following commands:

1. Using cmdlet `Update-SPUserSolution` you can update already activated sandbox solutions. The key point is `-ToSolution` parameter/attribute. Where you need to pass on the new Solution name. I used versioning in file name to overcome same solution identity conflict.
2. Now you can repeat step 3 to 5 from above (in-case new features are added).